# How can I repair epson printer head (if possible)

Tags: printing, printer

I have an epson ecotank printer which is printing black with blanks like this pattern

[image]

After having the printer examined by the epson support I was told that only replacing the print head can fix it. Before replacing it I would like to know if there's anything else I can do about it or at least give a try.

Any ideas?

Comment: They gave you good advice, as the print heads are not repairable. Check the pricing to replace as it may be more economical to replace the printer

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I've decided to make the printer my labrat now :D I'll try and take it apart and see if I can replace the print head myself. Any knowledge is good to have hehe. Because as you've said the price of having it replaced exceeds the current price of the printer.

Comment: If  you are able to replace the print head yourself that is worth trying. But check the price of the part so you know before you start.